# How to navigate manually with createBottomTabNavigator with existing createStackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have a `StackNavigator` as below. The `NavigationScreen` component has the bottom tab inside.

**App.js**

```
const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Login: LoginScreen,
    Home: NavigationScreen,
    ProductDetail: ProductDetailScreen,
    OrderDetail: OrderDetailScreen,
    Search: SearchScreen
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: "Login"
  }
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Root><AppContainer ref={navigatorRef => { setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef); }} /></Root>;
  }
}
```

On top of this I have a `BottomTabNavigator` which is created via `createBottomTabNavigator` in the `Home` screen.
Now I want to be able to manually navigate inside this `BottomTabNavigator`.

Is there any way to do this?

**NavigationScreen.js**

```
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Homepage: {
    screen: HomepageTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Image
                  source={focused ? homeActiveImg : homeImg }
                  style={styles.footerIcons}/>;
        },
    }
  },
  Products: { 
    screen: ProductsTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Image
                  source={focused ? productsActiveImg : productsImg }
                  style={styles.footerIcons}/>;
        },
    }
  },
  Orders: {
    screen: OrdersTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Image
                  source={focused ? ordersActiveImg : ordersImg }
                  style={styles.footerIcons}/>;
        },
    }
  },
  Users: { 
    screen: UsersTab,
    navigationOptions: {
        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, tintColor }) => {
          return <Image
                  source={focused ? usersActiveImg : usersImg }
                  style={styles.footerIcons}/>;
        },
    }
  }
},
{
  lazy: true
});

TabNavigator.navigationOptions =  navigation  => {
  return { header: null };
};

export default TabNavigator;
```

Comment: I don't understand where the bottomTab is placed. Is it a child of the stack?

Comment: @Auticcat you mean the navigator? it's a page inside the StackNavigator: Home: NavigationScreen, so when I navigate here, I get a page with bottom tab navigation.

Comment: If the screen screen inside bottomTabNavigator is a simple component and not another navigator, then you should be able to just navigation.navigate to the other tabs

Comment: @Auticcat I actually get undefined on navigation. Could you show me an example of what you mean?

Comment: For example, in UsersTab, you can add a button that has an onPress like: `onPress = () => this.props.navigation.navigate("Products")`

Comment: @Auticcat I can swear I tried this and it didn't work multiple times, I just tried `this.props.navigation.push('OrdersTab');` again and it worked. Thank you very much, I guess it was just a failure of the mind.

Comment: Strange that it worked tho, it's the navigation prop generated from the bottomTabNavigator, not from a stack. It shouldn't even have a function that is `push()`

Comment: @Auticcat Actually you are right. navigate() or push() both just open a new page like a pop up. They don't change the pages from the navigation tab. So with what you just said, this probably means that the this.prop.navigation is using the navigation from the stack somehow. Does anything come to your mind to work around this?

Comment: @Auticcat Where exactly am I supposed to use this `this.props.navigation.navigate("Products");`? Maybe I am using it in the wrong place.

Comment: Can you show the whole navigation structure? It shouldn’t act like that

Comment: @Auticcat okay this time I definitely fixed it. I have changed the key to `Orders2` from `Orders` and then put `tabBarLabel: 'Orders'` inside the `navigationOptions`, which then started working with `this.props.navigation.navigate("Orders2")`. I think there was a complication with the keys, but eventually `navigate()` worked as you suggested. Thanks a lot for your help! Your question pushed me to check into it.

Comment: No problem! Good that you figured it out ! Happy to help